# Nan value when reading DataFrame columns

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I am loading a large xlsx file to 'python' using 'pandas' 'DataFrame', the file has ~537k rows and some 30 columns.

First, I am flagging unique values and then I am trying to add a column with the sum of 'Approved' budget per 'year'.

But I keep getting a Nan value for both 'year' and 'Approved' columns. Finally, I am tracking the time that the code takes to calculate.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
import numpy as np
import time
start_time = time.perf_counter()

file_name= ('A:\somefile.xlsx')
sheet_name= ('6. Data')
data = pd.read_excel(io= file_name, sheet= sheet_name)
data_ltd = DataFrame(data, columns=['year','Approved'])
print("Column list: ",data_ltd.columns.tolist())


data_ltd['Duplicate?']= ~data_ltd.duplicated('year')
print(data_ltd.head())

data_ltd['$$']= data_ltd.groupby('year')['Approved'].transform('sum')
data_ltd['$$']= np.where(data_ltd['$$'].duplicated(), '-',data_ltd['$$'])
print(data_ltd.head(10))

print(time.perf_counter()-start_time)
```

**Output:**

```
year  Approved  Duplicate?
0   NaN       NaN        True
1   NaN       NaN       False
2   NaN       NaN       False
3   NaN       NaN       False
4   NaN       NaN       False
```

Needless to say, the code errors out and doesn't give me the column with the sum values.

Comment: You don't need to use `data_ltd = DataFrame(data, columns=['year','Approved'])`. It's already a dataframe

Comment: I did that just to limit the screen output. Do you think that is causing the Nan values?